# Are all change of basis matrices unitary?

Tags: linear-algebra

We know a unitary matrix preserves the norm of the vector it acts on, so it doesn't make intuitive sense that for **any** basis I choose, the norm of a vector will be preserved (considering it contracts for example). Is the saying "A change of basis matrix is unitary" false in some cases then?

Comment: I think there's an additional restriction that the bases must be orthonormal. Otherwise as you've pointed out I can simply stretch along an axis and this will clearly fail.

Comment: Any matrix can be a change of basis matrix as long as is it is nonsingular.

Answer (score 0):

Thinking about it in a physical situation, a basis where distances are measured in meters is every bit a "legitimate" basis as a basis where distances are measured in centimeters.  It's just a matter of which is more useful, given the problem at hand.  So, no, a change of basis matrix does not have to be unitary.